# Huffman Coding vs Arithmetic Coding

Tags: information-theory, hamming-code

Are there conditions under which given text $T$ that huffman code and arithmetic code will produce the exact encoding of $T$?

Comment: Of course. I assume it’s homework, so I’ll just say it’s really easy to show.

Comment: This is for preparation for the exam.A friend  told me that the exact opposite. Meaning that there are no conditions since Huffman is based on frequencies and the arithmetic takes the frequencies and uses them to find an interval. So if you say it's true what is the reason for that?

Comment: That's an argument why they are _usually_ different. Figure out _why_ arithmetic coding is usually more efficient. Then figure out in which situations is is _not_ more efficient, but exactly as efficient as Huffman. And there you get your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if all probabilities are in form of $2^{-k}$ then the arithmetic encoding will be the same as huffman encoding. both achieving the expected length of $H(X)$ (entropy).

In such conditions branching in arithmetic coding will be exact and behave the same way huffman coding does.